# User Defined Function with For loop returning "#VALUE!" error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a user-defined-function that returns the value of the Irwin-Hall distribution for given x and n.

I have successfully calculated the appropriate value using a table for each n-value, calculating the corresponding term of the Irwin-Hall series. In my understanding, the steps in doing this are identical to what I should expect my code to do.

```
Function IRWINHALLPDF(x As Double, n As Integer)

Dim IH As Double
Dim k As Integer


IH = 0


For k = 0 To n
    IH = IH + (-1) ^ k * WorksheetFunction.Combin(n, k) * (x - k) ^ (n - 1) * WorksheetFunction.Sign(x - k)
    Next k

    IH = IH / (2 * WorksheetFunction.Fact(n - 1))
    IRWINHALLPDF = IH

End Function
```

When used in the worksheet, the function returns the #VALUE! error. It appears as though each worksheet function is reciving proper inputs throughout the loop, so I cannot see why it would return the error.

Comment: @AxelRichter its Sgn no Sng, correct ?

Comment: There is no `WorksheetFunction.Sign`. Do using `VBA` function `Sgn` instead.

Comment: I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit` to avoid such typos: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from Axel Richter, Error with Sign Function

```
Function IRWINHALLPDF(x As Double, n As Integer) As Double

Dim IH As Double
Dim k As Integer


IH = 0


For k = 0 To n
    IH = IH + (-1) ^ k * WorksheetFunction.Combin(n, k) * (x - k) ^ (n - 1) * Sgn(x - k)
Next k

IH = IH / (2 * WorksheetFunction.Fact(n - 1))
IRWINHALLPDF = IH


End Function
```